# Reverse proxy based on DNS for multiple mysql hosts

Tags: mysql, nginx, tcp, proxy, routes

I've some mysql host in private network and would like to use a reverse proxy server (i.e. nginx) to connect with mysql-client to mysql host via reverse proxy server.

An example to better understand my answer:

suppose I've:

- a mysql server with ip yyy.1
- a mysql server with ip yyy.2

both in the network of a proxy server with ip XXX, and I associate to XXX the DNS mysql-server1.com and mysql-server2.com.

My goal is connect to mysql server **yyy.1** when I use mysql client to connect to **XXX** by calling **mysql-server1.com** on port **3306**, and similare when try mysql-server2.com on port 3306.

The problem with nginx is that I can't differenciate TCP request by server name, so in XXX server I should associate one port foreach mysql server, but this implies that every time I should change the port also in mysql client settings, and I don't wanna this!

There's some proxy-server that can accomplish that? 
Could I use IP Table to route the request **mysql-server1.com:3306** to **localhost:[some port]**, where I could use [some port] in proxy setting to forward the requests to the server **yyy.1**?

Answer (score 2):

This is impossible.

In the MySQL Client/Server protocol, the client never identifies the hostname to which it is attempting to connect to.  Unlike in some other protocols, such as HTTP (with the `Host` header), the original name the client used to resolve an IP address from DNS is not preserved.  TLS SNI is also not available, because TLS negotiation on a MySQL connection does not begin until the client reads the server capability flags to discover whether the server supports TLS, at which point the client asks to switch the connection to TLS... and this, of course, is after the connection is is already established.

In the MySQL Client/Server protocol, the server always talks first.

Your only options are for the proxy machine to listen on multiple IP addresses, with a DNS hostname pointing to each IP, and use the address to which the client connected to determine which server to use.

Or, each proxy instance listens on a separate port.

The protocol design prevents name-based virtual hosting.

Comment: Many thanks! I thought that the problem could be in protocol and your confirm is very precious!